# package com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder does not exist

Tags: java, matlab, compilation

I need my matlab code run in Java, but errors occured during deploying process, I couldn't compile the Java source file.

Here are the compilation errors:

```
C:\Users\HT\Untitled1\src\Untitled1\Class1.java:12: error: package com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder does not exist
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
^
C:\Users\HT\Untitled1\src\Untitled1\Class1.java:13: error: package com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal does not exist
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.*;
^

...

[checking Untitled1.Class1Remote]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/IOException.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Exception.class)]]
[total 1270ms]
43 errors

Error: An error occurred while shelling out to javac (error code = 1).
Unable to build executable.
```

I'm sure that `javac` was added in computer's environment variables.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with `javac` itself. The in the error message mentioned package is just not present in the compile time classpath.

Comment: Do you set any compilation classpath information at all?

Comment: @Thomas, BalusC : How could I set any compilation? Sorry, im just java beginner :(... Thanks...

Comment: Btw, i already added javabuider.jar into Libraries(Java build path) in Eclipse...

Comment: Well, adding something to the build path in Eclipse has nothing to do with javac on the command line. To add the classpath at command line, use the `-classpath` or `-cp` option. For more information have a look at the javac documentation.

Comment: If you will paste/mention the command that you ran to compile the java source file then it will help us to suggest you the more appropriate method to solve the problem. There can be multiple reasons for this error. Check your Java file name, path to MATLAB installation directory, JAR file name, parameters (if there) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the full path to `javabuilder.jar` to the classpath, not just the directory that contains it, eg: `d:\matlab\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar`.

Here is an [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) you should read to understand the PATH/CLASSPATH.

Comment: I tried to add Javabulider to javac -classpath, and when i typed echo %CLASSPATH% i got D:\MATLAB\toolbox\javabuilder\jar (where contains javabuilder.jav) but it doesn't work, the same errors happended....:(

Comment: @NguyenHoaiThanh: you want add the full path to `javabuilder.jar` to the classpath, not just the directory that contains it

Comment: As @Amro said, put also the .jar into the path. eg: d:\matlab\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar